# Surprising results obtained using lmfit minimize default minimization method

Tags: python, lmfit

I am using lmfit to look for the parameters that optimize the fit of a model to molecular spectra. The residual program invokes a Fortran code that computes the energy level and matches them with the available experimental data, providing the set of residuals that are the input to lmfit-minimize.

There are two possible cases: linear and non-linear molecules. I prepare one example for each of them. With linear molecules the output is what I would expect, reaching the same minimum than a previous code of mine that uses the Fortran version of Minuit for parameter optimization. This is an example, where that values printed are the Chi square values obtained each time the function is called.

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, fit_report
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
#
%run ../../bin/residuals_U3.py
input_filename = "HNC_input_file"
BENT = ".F."
exp_data_file="exp_HNC_Danielle.dat"
N_val=60
LMAX=7
VMAX=7
EMINL=".F."

U3H_FIT_param=Parameters()
U3H_FIT_param.add('P11',value=2390.0, vary=True)
U3H_FIT_param.add('P21',value=-37.0,vary=True)
U3H_FIT_param.add('P22',value=21.0, vary=True)
U3H_FIT_param.add('P23',value=-9.0, vary=True)

out_0 = minimize(residuals_U3, U3H_FIT_param, args=(input_filename, BENT, 
exp_data_file, N_val, LMAX, VMAX, EMINL))
31298390.0981
31298390.0981
31298390.0981
31298405.9262
31298393.7425
31298390.2979
31298399.7958
1239848240.71
....
5.7028931985
5.70223335575
5.68090132895
5.67973533085
5.68050720657
5.68089119394
5.68021995958
5.57489186835
5.57489701562
5.57489288067
5.57489188595
5.57489412245
5.57489158478

print fit_report(out_0)
[[Fit Statistics]]
# function evals   = 169
# data points      = 19
# variables        = 4
chi-square         = 5.575
reduced chi-square = 0.372
Akaike info crit   = -15.297
Bayesian info crit = -11.519
[[Variables]]
P11:   2375.84727 +/- 59.96417 (2.52%) (init= 2390)
P21:  -37.5581932 +/- 1.065396 (2.84%) (init=-37)
P22:   19.2964371 +/- 0.426936 (2.21%) (init= 21)
P23:  -9.63266677 +/- 0.261630 (2.72%) (init=-9)
P31:   0 (fixed)
P32:   0 (fixed)
P33:   0 (fixed)
P41:   0 (fixed)
P42:   0 (fixed)
P43:   0 (fixed)
P44:   0 (fixed)
P45:   0 (fixed)
P46:   0 (fixed)
P47:   0 (fixed)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
C(P11, P23)                  = -1.000 
C(P11, P21)                  = -1.000 
C(P21, P23)                  =  1.000 
C(P22, P23)                  = -1.000 
C(P11, P22)                  =  1.000 
C(P21, P22)                  = -1.000 code here
```

So far so good. The problem arises once I tried to fit data from a non-linear molecular species. Then, after very few evaluations, the program seems to converge to the initial values provided. If we call this example 1:

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, fit_report                 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE                         


%run ../../bin/residuals_U3.py       

input_filename = "NCNCS_input_file"                        
BENT = ".T."               
exp_data_file="test_exp_NCNCS.dat"                         
N_val=70               
LMAX=9                 
VMAX=6                 
EMINL=".F."            

# Parameters far from the minimum I already know                   
U3H_FIT_param=Parameters()       
U3H_FIT_param.add('P11',value=200.0, vary=True)                    
U3H_FIT_param.add('P21',value=-2.60,vary=True)                     
U3H_FIT_param.add('P22',value=1.50, vary=True)                     
U3H_FIT_param.add('P23',value=-0.8, vary=True)                     


out_0 = minimize(residuals_U3, U3H_FIT_param, args=(input_filename, BENT, exp_data_file, N_val, LMAX, VMAX, EMINL))        
33820.0608635              
33820.0608635              
33820.0608635              
33942.2383744              
34935.7037896              
33810.3126988              
33357.9527561              
33303.3818229              
34574.0192135              
34526.2057525              
33337.2494285              
34458.8982496              
34798.9915284              

print fit_report(out_0)        
[[Fit Statistics]]         
    # function evals   = 13       
    # data points      = 70       
    # variables        = 4       
    chi-square         = 33303.382                         
    reduced chi-square = 504.597                           
    Akaike info crit   = 439.544                           
    Bayesian info crit = 448.538                           
[[Variables]]              
    P11:   199.999988 +/- 4.02e-05 (0.00%) (init= 200)                 
    P21:  -2.60000161 +/- 6.71e-07 (0.00%) (init=-2.6)                 
    P22:   1.50000025 +/- 3.57e-07 (0.00%) (init= 1.5)                 
    P23:  -0.79999987 +/- 2.12e-07 (0.00%) (init=-0.8)                 
    P31:   0 (fixed)           
    P32:   0 (fixed)           
    P33:   0 (fixed)           
    P41:   0 (fixed)           
    P42:   0 (fixed)           
    P43:   0 (fixed)           
    P44:   0 (fixed)           
    P45:   0 (fixed)           
    P46:   0 (fixed)           
    P47:   0 (fixed)           
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)                
    C(P21, P23)                  = -0.675                      
    C(P21, P22)                  =  0.506                      
    C(P22, P23)                  = -0.430                      
    C(P11, P21)                  = -0.420                      
    C(P11, P23)                  = -0.317                      
    C(P11, P22)                  = -0.216
```

If we repeat example 1 with a more verbose output that includes, apart from Chi^2 as previously, the parameter values and the residuals obtained we have:

```
U3H_FIT_param=Parameters()   
U3H_FIT_param.add('P11',value=200.0, vary=True)                  
U3H_FIT_param.add('P21',value=-2.60,vary=True)                   
U3H_FIT_param.add('P22',value=1.50, vary=True)                   
U3H_FIT_param.add('P23',value=-0.8, vary=True)                   


out_0 = minimize(residuals_U3, U3H_FIT_param, args=(input_filename, BENT, exp_data_file, N_val, LMAX, VMAX, EMINL))      
&INP1b P11=200.0 /       

&INP2b P21=-2.6, P22=1.5, P23=-0.8 / 

RESIDUALS  [  0.          -3.75658039 -10.85664646 -18.29270568 -21.23633151     
 -23.97010961 -27.99053887  -0.28486237  -3.86773685  -9.31351971        
 -15.92856641 -20.2686777  -24.7703342  -30.12984172  -0.8655828         
  -4.27628737  -9.23390995 -15.22920459 -20.20446745 -25.50896835        
 -31.54014503  -1.98904718  -5.28870374  -9.64523663 -14.86388301        
 -20.30393994 -26.28976779 -32.87036748  -3.4154388   -5.99093571        
 -10.52895266 -15.51556868 -21.64134653 -27.44348466 -35.0922282         
  -4.59343935  -7.18069815 -11.05888025 -16.24498349 -22.25796287        
 -29.17718901 -37.86040995  -6.82393206  -8.37059213 -12.37991401        
 -17.32380238 -23.6259757  -30.77116529 -39.6603254   -7.37663293        
  -9.4855129  -13.15066135 -18.13207261 -24.54463108 -33.16897104        
 -43.02725922  -8.32876467 -10.8207887  -14.54627353 -19.60041984        
 -26.69368656 -34.95192225 -46.08130388  -9.44803578 -11.71293473        
 -15.45927873 -21.18174524 -28.33172007 -37.40255102 -49.41886369]       
33820.0608635            


&INP1b P11=200.0 /       

&INP2b P21=-2.6, P22=1.5, P23=-0.8 / 

RESIDUALS  [  0.          -3.75658039 -10.85664646 -18.29270568 -21.23633151     
 -23.97010961 -27.99053887  -0.28486237  -3.86773685  -9.31351971        
 -15.92856641 -20.2686777  -24.7703342  -30.12984172  -0.8655828         
  -4.27628737  -9.23390995 -15.22920459 -20.20446745 -25.50896835        
 -31.54014503  -1.98904718  -5.28870374  -9.64523663 -14.86388301        
 -20.30393994 -26.28976779 -32.87036748  -3.4154388   -5.99093571        
 -10.52895266 -15.51556868 -21.64134653 -27.44348466 -35.0922282         
  -4.59343935  -7.18069815 -11.05888025 -16.24498349 -22.25796287        
 -29.17718901 -37.86040995  -6.82393206  -8.37059213 -12.37991401        
 -17.32380238 -23.6259757  -30.77116529 -39.6603254   -7.37663293        
  -9.4855129  -13.15066135 -18.13207261 -24.54463108 -33.16897104        
 -43.02725922  -8.32876467 -10.8207887  -14.54627353 -19.60041984        
 -26.69368656 -34.95192225 -46.08130388  -9.44803578 -11.71293473        
 -15.45927873 -21.18174524 -28.33172007 -37.40255102 -49.41886369]       
33820.0608635            


&INP1b P11=200.0 /       

&INP2b P21=-2.6, P22=1.5, P23=-0.8 / 

RESIDUALS  [  0.          -3.75658039 -10.85664646 -18.29270568 -21.23633151     
 -23.97010961 -27.99053887  -0.28486237  -3.86773685  -9.31351971        
 -15.92856641 -20.2686777  -24.7703342  -30.12984172  -0.8655828         
  -4.27628737  -9.23390995 -15.22920459 -20.20446745 -25.50896835        
 -31.54014503  -1.98904718  -5.28870374  -9.64523663 -14.86388301        
 -20.30393994 -26.28976779 -32.87036748  -3.4154388   -5.99093571        
 -10.52895266 -15.51556868 -21.64134653 -27.44348466 -35.0922282         
  -4.59343935  -7.18069815 -11.05888025 -16.24498349 -22.25796287        
 -29.17718901 -37.86040995  -6.82393206  -8.37059213 -12.37991401        
 -17.32380238 -23.6259757  -30.77116529 -39.6603254   -7.37663293        
  -9.4855129  -13.15066135 -18.13207261 -24.54463108 -33.16897104        
 -43.02725922  -8.32876467 -10.8207887  -14.54627353 -19.60041984        
 -26.69368656 -34.95192225 -46.08130388  -9.44803578 -11.71293473        
 -15.45927873 -21.18174524 -28.33172007 -37.40255102 -49.41886369]       
33820.0608635            

.....                

&INP1b P11=199.999988473 /   

&INP2b P21=-2.60000161305, P22=1.50000025484, P23=-0.799999875067 /      

RESIDUALS  [  0.          -3.99268261 -11.73264434 -19.05089687 -21.8743998  
 -23.98786565 -28.05424445  -0.80354366  -4.29117203 -10.41169177        
 -16.11475578 -20.76739082 -24.72907688 -29.96025254  -1.19554552        
  -4.77165975 -10.04051152 -15.40288703 -20.18713017 -25.8307694         
 -31.91088782  -2.46101195  -5.74047469  -9.9850673  -15.24025329        
 -20.72837057 -26.68827531 -33.31621124  -3.66948178  -6.53021075        
 -10.89700164 -15.81327816 -21.81723225 -28.08793728 -35.76616676        
  -4.99405722  -7.65935238 -11.55129453 -16.5529505  -22.40531267        
 -29.36326533 -38.30271257  -7.21713077  -8.76345313 -12.77142684        
 -17.71182548 -24.01827081 -31.19676872 -40.10579542  -7.61666334        
  -9.92207061 -13.58164103 -18.52451949 -25.03610104 -33.39256778        
 -43.32754575  -8.67692476 -11.12324272 -15.00726898 -20.04660062        
 -27.02514438 -35.41059799 -46.51995156 -10.18456526 -12.0963503         
 -15.60152462 -21.17712212 -28.94048104 -37.94146875 -49.83299737]       
34798.9915284            

print fit_report(out_0)      
[[Fit Statistics]]       
    # function evals   = 13  
    # data points      = 70  
    # variables        = 4   
    chi-square         = 33303.382 
    reduced chi-square = 504.597 
    Akaike info crit   = 439.544 
    Bayesian info crit = 448.538 
[[Variables]]            
    P11:   199.999988 +/- 4.02e-05 (0.00%) (init= 200)               
    P21:  -2.60000161 +/- 6.71e-07 (0.00%) (init=-2.6)               
    P22:   1.50000025 +/- 3.57e-07 (0.00%) (init= 1.5)               
    P23:  -0.79999987 +/- 2.12e-07 (0.00%) (init=-0.8)               
    P31:   0 (fixed)         
    P32:   0 (fixed)         
    P33:   0 (fixed)         
    P41:   0 (fixed)         
    P42:   0 (fixed)         
    P43:   0 (fixed)         
    P44:   0 (fixed)         
    P45:   0 (fixed)         
    P46:   0 (fixed)         
    P47:   0 (fixed)         
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)              
    C(P21, P23)                  = -0.675                    
    C(P21, P22)                  =  0.506                    
    C(P22, P23)                  = -0.430                    
    C(P11, P21)                  = -0.420                    
    C(P11, P23)                  = -0.317                    
    C(P11, P22)                  = -0.216
```

There is clearly a better minimum as the example (example 2) shows:

```
# Parameters closer to the minimum
U3H_FIT_param=Parameters()       
U3H_FIT_param.add('P11',value=201.0, vary=True)                    
U3H_FIT_param.add('P21',value=-2.570,vary=True)                    
U3H_FIT_param.add('P22',value=1.4980, vary=True)                   
U3H_FIT_param.add('P23',value=-0.81, vary=True)  


out_0 = minimize(residuals_U3, U3H_FIT_param, args=(input_filename, BENT, exp_data_file, N_val, LMAX, VMAX, EMINL))        
866.43578979               
866.43578979               
866.43578979               
880.37396166               
890.227624754              
852.194331523              
780.074380341              
801.333830227              

print fit_report(out_0)        
[[Fit Statistics]]         
    # function evals   = 8       
    # data points      = 70       
    # variables        = 4       
    chi-square         = 801.334                           
    reduced chi-square = 12.141       
    Akaike info crit   = 178.645                           
    Bayesian info crit = 187.639                           
[[Variables]]              
    P11:   200.999990 +/- 7.47e-06 (0.00%) (init= 201)                 
    P21:  -2.57000013 +/- 1.08e-07 (0.00%) (init=-2.57)                
    P22:   1.49800011 +/- 5.88e-08 (0.00%) (init= 1.498)               
    P23:  -0.80999997 +/- 8.11e-09 (0.00%) (init=-0.81)                
    P31:   0 (fixed)           
    P32:   0 (fixed)           
    P33:   0 (fixed)           
    P41:   0 (fixed)           
    P42:   0 (fixed)           
    P43:   0 (fixed)           
    P44:   0 (fixed)           
    P45:   0 (fixed)           
    P46:   0 (fixed)           
    P47:   0 (fixed)           
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)                
    C(P11, P21)                  = -0.386                      
    C(P11, P22)                  = -0.379                      
    C(P21, P23)                  =  0.263                      
    C(P11, P23)                  = -0.125
```

However, if in this bent case I change the minimization method, e.g. to nelder, the results are as expected, even if I start the minimization quite far from the minimum as in example 1:

```
U3H_FIT_param=Parameters()            
U3H_FIT_param.add('P11',value=200.0, vary=True)      
U3H_FIT_param.add('P21',value=-2.60,vary=True)      
U3H_FIT_param.add('P22',value=1.50, vary=True)      
U3H_FIT_param.add('P23',value=-0.8, vary=True)      


out_0 = minimize(residuals_U3, U3H_FIT_param, args=(input_filename, BENT, exp_data_file, N_val, LMAX, VMAX, EMINL), method = "nelder")        
33820.0608635                     
386363.244872                     
540126.50767                      
27839.1627683                     
21180.6786213                     
398690.128256                     
105124.802101                     
98763.3226762                     
332146.050613                     
3785.18423466                     
175555.611803                     
45570.4112121                     
15015.0822576                     
20437.4181311                     
76313.1360929                     
3192.21680729                     
...                       
355.980240836                     
332.571174789                     
332.571174789                     
355.980240836                     
350.020618839                     
358.718935527                     
332.571174789                     
332.571174789                     
332.571174789                     
332.571174789                     
print fit_report(out_0)               
[[Fit Statistics]]                
    # function evals   = 280              
    # data points      = 70           
    # variables        = 4            
    chi-square         = 332.571          
    reduced chi-square = 5.039            
    Akaike info crit   = 117.085          
    Bayesian info crit = 126.079          
[[Variables]]                     
    P11:   201.428112 (init= 200)         
    P21:  -2.58733894 (init=-2.6)         
    P22:   1.52918377 (init= 1.5)         
    P23:  -0.81586079 (init=-0.8)         
    P31:   0 (fixed)                  
    P32:   0 (fixed)                  
    P33:   0 (fixed)                  
    P41:   0 (fixed)                  
    P42:   0 (fixed)                  
    P43:   0 (fixed)                  
    P44:   0 (fixed)                  
    P45:   0 (fixed)                  
    P46:   0 (fixed)                  
    P47:   0 (fixed)                  
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
```

In this case the more verbose output for some of the iterations is the following

```
U3H_FIT_param=Parameters()     
U3H_FIT_param.add('P11',value=200.0, vary=True)                  
U3H_FIT_param.add('P21',value=-2.60,vary=True)                   
U3H_FIT_param.add('P22',value=1.50, vary=True)                   
U3H_FIT_param.add('P23',value=-0.8, vary=True)                   

out_0 = minimize(residuals_U3, U3H_FIT_param, args=(input_filename, BENT, exp_data_file, N_val, LMAX, VMAX, EMINL), method = "nelder")                       
&INP1b P11=200.0 /       

&INP2b P21=-2.6, P22=1.5, P23=-0.8 /                         

RESIDUALS  [  0.          -3.75658039 -10.85664646 -18.29270568 -21.23633151     
 -23.97010961 -27.99053887  -0.28486237  -3.86773685  -9.31351971        
 -15.92856641 -20.2686777  -24.7703342  -30.12984172  -0.8655828         
  -4.27628737  -9.23390995 -15.22920459 -20.20446745 -25.50896835        
 -31.54014503  -1.98904718  -5.28870374  -9.64523663 -14.86388301        
 -20.30393994 -26.28976779 -32.87036748  -3.4154388   -5.99093571        
 -10.52895266 -15.51556868 -21.64134653 -27.44348466 -35.0922282         
  -4.59343935  -7.18069815 -11.05888025 -16.24498349 -22.25796287        
 -29.17718901 -37.86040995  -6.82393206  -8.37059213 -12.37991401        
 -17.32380238 -23.6259757  -30.77116529 -39.6603254   -7.37663293        
  -9.4855129  -13.15066135 -18.13207261 -24.54463108 -33.16897104        
 -43.02725922  -8.32876467 -10.8207887  -14.54627353 -19.60041984        
 -26.69368656 -34.95192225 -46.08130388  -9.44803578 -11.71293473        
 -15.45927873 -21.18174524 -28.33172007 -37.40255102 -49.41886369]       
33820.0608635            


&INP1b P11=210.0 /       

&INP2b P21=-2.6, P22=1.5, P23=-0.8 /                         

RESIDUALS  [   0.          -26.16300891  -35.92631045  -18.8046449     7.84306164                        
   29.85328814   49.35183801    5.44122598   -7.20663588   -7.51532458       
    5.28787982   22.79715815   41.85783891   59.23158371   14.12838386       
    9.2311941    12.82257834   24.05402553   39.05684174   54.70325573       
   69.54410104   24.02558592   24.14278484   30.06592218   40.05349953       
   53.44068403   67.14018094   80.79972754   33.95012425   37.30408452       
   44.53432899   54.88610982   67.23500121   79.31052971   91.39583861       
   44.20244335   49.60557888   58.08586594   68.72834808   79.93361024       
   91.24600502  101.35283675   53.69459696   61.88966887   70.56905834       
   80.97053725   91.89016079  102.16450603  111.61917172   64.64821697       
   73.47362861   82.86652184   93.10114386  103.25734084  112.65601867       
  120.69284205   75.35070819   84.29816695   94.28958114  104.26041597       
  113.8639484   122.29150128  129.26978921   85.42971752   95.71850413       
  105.5315729   115.31685183  124.24099756  132.05550135  137.78892407]      
386363.244872            


&INP1b P11=200.0 /       

&INP2b P21=-2.73, P22=1.5, P23=-0.8 /                        

RESIDUALS  [   0.           -6.51482403  -11.84722003  -17.94556936  -34.33607138                        
  -57.67632401  -81.40734149   -1.63845707   -8.55295725  -17.17160577       
  -29.53548333  -47.97384287  -69.24130491  -94.24014416   -4.42106668       
  -13.37478867  -25.1140549   -40.25940819  -59.31786691  -81.45795179       
 -106.40406773   -8.47241409  -19.88180645  -33.26697111  -49.98215925       
  -70.28802414  -93.70400896 -119.18639263  -14.91219834  -26.42593577       
  -41.64563448  -60.30755635  -81.61793552 -105.65083382 -132.51508599       
  -20.93474386  -34.42278364  -50.99246305  -70.22964079  -92.3174835        
 -117.92944692 -146.19607146  -29.37468772  -42.38500645  -59.95420309       
  -80.42758498 -103.61555313 -130.08637485 -159.51597624  -35.8953851        
  -51.09068006  -69.33552966  -90.56701074 -114.87032877 -142.75145306       
 -173.6936809   -43.62317666  -59.85538811  -79.26959621 -101.53354992       
 -126.78686941 -155.31065489 -187.76051864  -52.18050662  -68.57148933       
  -88.53569045 -111.87500818 -138.66419476 -168.68410045 -203.08199158]      
540126.50767
```

........................

```
&INP1b P11=201.428112052 /     

&INP2b P21=-2.58733894638, P22=1.52918377018, P23=-0.815860796044 /      

RESIDUALS  [ 0.          2.70481025  2.5647914  -0.66779985 -1.84848475 -2.294670
 -2.8511186  -0.06763408  2.30399185  2.4069086   0.60429218 -1.17025016     
 -1.7678735  -2.25363581 -0.97533799  1.89312414  2.19413958  1.4505511      
 -0.1054865  -1.2606611  -2.4558844  -1.59327497  0.99634674  1.79137313     
  1.42330317  0.81319402 -0.59261343 -1.9298181  -2.60320618  0.49113672     
  1.90950601  1.62687398  1.43875694  0.03109259 -2.37265779 -3.45057765     
  0.19965851  1.72320248  2.2898178   1.34013775  0.40188506 -2.25368524     
 -4.79999944 -0.29638363  1.49036912  2.26290378  1.88161992  0.70066741     
 -2.00055299 -4.2727996  -0.37954819  2.06048067  3.136022    2.91270888     
  0.68341221 -2.54241374 -4.11982953 -0.25818249  2.16914822  3.46019775     
  2.91502288  1.04311452 -2.62395441 -3.82618485  0.00951645  2.95514821     
  3.92300846  3.37200094  1.280833   -3.34939407]                
332.571174789            


&INP1b P11=201.428112052 /     

&INP2b P21=-2.58733894638, P22=1.52918377018, P23=-0.815860796044 /      

RESIDUALS  [ 0.          2.70481025  2.5647914  -0.66779985 -1.84848475 -2.29467012 
 -2.8511186  -0.06763408  2.30399185  2.4069086   0.60429218 -1.17025016     
 -1.7678735  -2.25363581 -0.97533799  1.89312414  2.19413958  1.4505511      
 -0.1054865  -1.2606611  -2.4558844  -1.59327497  0.99634674  1.79137313     
  1.42330317  0.81319402 -0.59261343 -1.9298181  -2.60320618  0.49113672     
  1.90950601  1.62687398  1.43875694  0.03109259 -2.37265779 -3.45057765     
  0.19965851  1.72320248  2.2898178   1.34013775  0.40188506 -2.25368524     
 -4.79999944 -0.29638363  1.49036912  2.26290378  1.88161992  0.70066741     
 -2.00055299 -4.2727996  -0.37954819  2.06048067  3.136022    2.91270888     
  0.68341221 -2.54241374 -4.11982953 -0.25818249  2.16914822  3.46019775     
  2.91502288  1.04311452 -2.62395441 -3.82618485  0.00951645  2.95514821     
  3.92300846  3.37200094  1.280833   -3.34939407]                
332.571174789
```

I would appreciate any explanation or guess of why the default (Levenberg-Marquardt method) may be failing or if there is a way of tuning it to overcome this problem.

Comment: I think you need to give us more to go on.  Can you post the residual function? You might try adding calls to `print()` there to see how it is using the parameters to calculate the residual array.  Also, the initial values changed a fair amount between the different calls to minimize() -- why would that be?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The problem involves a parameter-dependent Hamiltonian matrix diagonalization and the comparison of the obtained energy values with experimental term values. The output of the residual function is this set of energy differences (residuals). This calculation involves a Fortran program and I used to perform the parameter optimization with the Minuit Fortran subroutine. I will try to extract the parameter values from the residual function as you suggest to see if this can help..

Comment: @curix, It's hard to diagnose a problem without seeing the objective function. Since the other methods work with the same objective function, it seems like the objective function must return an array of values without any `nan` or `inf` values.... Those would cause such problems. If you call the objective function yourself (ie, outside of the fit) with the starting parameter values or small variations of those, do you get a changing residual?  Can you change the parameter values by a tiny amount and get a numerically different result? Those would all be necessary for `leastsq` to work.

Comment: @MNewville I will edit my original question to include information about the parameters and the residuals. Maybe this can be of help. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: @MNewville Done. Sorry for the too wordy and lengthy question.

Comment: is that helpful to you? It's not particularly helpful to *me*, but I hope it it to you.  At the risk of repeating myself, if **you** call the residual function (that you refuse to post) with parameters with **very small** differences (say 1.e-8, which is what `leastsq()` will typically do), do you see a difference in your residual array?  But also, you are asking for help, and not giving requested information or answering explicit and direct follow up questions.   If you want help in the future, you'll probably learn to do those things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167707/discussion-between-currix-and-m-newville).